# Google OAuth SSO provider and Restricted Domain

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, authentication, google-apps, custom-domain

We have setup Google login via OAuth for our Salesforce (Not SAML) and authentication via our custom domain page works fine. But as soon as we try to restrict our users to **login** only from our domain page (In *Setup->Domain Management->My Domain->Login Policy: Prevent login from https://login.salesforce.com*), this method for authentication fails when initiated from our custom domain, with the following error:

> Problem Logging In
>   We can’t log you in because of an authentication error. For help, contact your Salesforce administrator.

When I go and visit the login history I notice the following entry associated with this failed login attempt:

> Login Type: Third Party SSO
>   Status: Restricted Domain

As soon as I loosen that restriction, login via Google starts working again.

I've followed this guide to setup SSO: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_google.htm&type=5

I've used this code for my registration handler: https://github.com/trineo/sfdc-rego-handler/blob/master/src/classes/GoogleAppsRegistrationHandler.cls

Comment: The oauth flow from google is likely redirecting the user back to login.salesforce.com/auth/sso... Change that url in your auth provider config to be yourdomain.my.salesforce.com/auth/sso...

Comment: @GregGrinberg Interesting thought. I don't see any reference to login.salesforce.com either on my google apis/services or in salesforce auth provider. can you point me to where you're referring to?

Comment: When you set up the authentication provider for Google in Salesforce, did you accept Salesforce's managed values or did you configure it manually? You likely just need to modify the endpoint URLs for the my domain. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=5

Comment: @MarkPond I only have entered my consumer key, secret and registration handler, everything else was left as default

Comment: @RezaS what is the callback URL that you see when you go to the Auth Provider detail page that you have configured? It should be under Salesforce Configuration section on the AUth Provider page. Do you find something as: https://login.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/xxxxx/Google_OAuth

Comment: @JayantDas It is: https://<mydomain>.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/Google

Comment: @RezaS have you configured a Google OAuth provider in your case? If yes, can you check in the Google console if the same callback URL is configured in there? Or it redirects to login.salesforce.com?

Comment: @RezaS I was able to replicate the issue that you are having. Couldn't find anything yet except for the link to this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213324&type=1). Seems to be a platform issue as even after logging in through the domain, the login fails if "prevent from login..." is enabled. Will research and see if I find anything.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like to be an issue which was fixed with Summer '17, that may have resurfaced. Refer to this known issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAHzQAO&title=summer-17-unable-to-log-in-to-sandbox-with-my-domain-prevent-login-from-https-test-salesforce-com-post-enabled-post-upgrade).

You may like to reach out to Salesforce support to verify and get details on this, if that's the case.

Update: The issue specifically seems to be in the SSO flow as if you login using the my domain url and use your salesforce credentials, it works fine even if "prevent login.." is checked. This could possibly be part of the issue that was fixed with Summer '17 only for my domain urls but not the SSO flow.

Answer (score 1):

What is the URL you entered in step 5 of the setup? If you used the sample URL that contains the 'login.salesforce.com' part, your login most likely fails when you prevent users from login in via this URL.

I would suggest replacing the login.salesforce.com part with your custom domain that you have configured and try again.

UPDATE: Based on the below comment it's probably not in step 5. Once you saved your Auth. Provider, it will provide you with the following URLs:

```
Test-Only Initialization URL
Single Sign-On Initialization URL
Existing User Linking URL
OAuth-Only Initialization URL
Single Logout URL
```

Those URLs must be specific to your my domain settings.

Comment: step 5 talks about setting a URL suffix, not an actual URL (it has a 32 char limit). For us that's currently set to "Google"

Comment: @RezaS that's actually a good point. I'll update my reply.

Comment: all those 6 domains are off of my custom domain @Jannis Bott